# Customize QGIS interface

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, query, gui

I'm writing here to ask some questions for a thesis project. My ideas are confused, but I'll try to be clear.

I have a GIS project that represents some historical goods in a region. Each good has some attributes that describes the entity (like a date, a role, etc.). My task is to create a list of queries (for example: select and represents all goods that have a defined role in a defined time) and create an interface, using QGIS, that allows to represent:

1. A menu to choose the query,
2. A form to input informations,
3. A way to customize the presentations of results into the map and a table.

I know that my question is too broad, but to be more clear I need:

1. To know which tools allow to customize QGIS's interface (icons, fonts, colors, all that is possible),
2. Examples of QGIS projects where these two features are present: 1) customized interface, 2) possibility to query.

To help I'll attach a sketch of how the interface should be.

[image]

I'm asking if there's a way to presents the results of a query in a view like the one in my sketch, where there's the map, but also a table.

Answer (score 4):

> to know which tools allow to customize QGIS's interface

To customize the QGIS interface, go to the Settings menu > Customize Interface. Also have a look at the options available in the Settings menu > Options.

The customization options should be mostly self-explanatory. See the [interface customization section of the QGIS Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#sec-customization) for more details.

> create a list of queries

Try a [Rule-Based Style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-renderer). You can define different rules (queries) on the same layer. In the layers panel, there will be check-boxes that allow you to select which query you want to see on the map.

> a form to input informations

When the user [creates a new feature](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#adding-features) in an existing layer, QGIS will give them a form to fill in the attributes for that feature. If you set up a layer with the required attributes, the user will have the option to fill in those attributes.

If you don't like the standard attribute entry form that QGIS creates, you can design a custom form in the layer properties dialogue > attributes form.

> presents the results of a query in a view like the one in my sketch, where there's the map, but also a table

To produce an interactive map with table (ie, one where the user can pan and zoom the map, or select an item from the table and zoon to it, etc), dock an attribute table at the bottom of the screen and choose the attribute table option to "show only features visible on the map.

- Open the layer's attribute table, and dock it by clicking the `Dock attribute table` button. From the menu in the bottom-left corner of the attribute table, choose the option to "show features visible on map."

  [image]
- You can make those the default setting for attribute tables, so you don't have to set up the attribute table every time you open it. Go to the Settings menu > Options > Data Sources.

  [image]

To produce a static map and table (eg to print or publish as a PDF document), use the [Print Layout](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/index.html). Add a map item and an attribute item to the print layout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's a start point very very usefull. About the last request (a way to customize presentations of results), I'm asking if there's a way to presents the results of a query in a view like the one in my sketch, where there's the map, but also a table. Thank you again, I'm not an expert and it's not easy to find what I need in the qgis documentation. Regards

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added some detail to my last point. I hope that helps. Feel free to start a new question if you get stuck on any part. Try to keep each question narrowly focused on a single thing you're trying to achieve, and don't be afraid to ask multiple questions. That makes it easier for people to understand each question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again, since you are the only one who gave me useful information so far, I take this opportunity to deepen my problem. What I'm looking for isn't so complicated: a UI where you can choose a query from a predefined list, enter the necessary information into a form, run the query and view the results (map and table). The final result should be an application light and simple not only for expert end-users. Now, in this first step, I'm trying to understand if it's better to create a "personal" version of QGis or if it's better to create a Web application. I don't know which approach is more suitable for my purposes. I'd wish to figure out if working with web libraries, like LeafLet or OpenLayers, it would be easier than using QGis. What do you think? Despite your precious information, I still haven't figured it out if QGis allows to do to do everything I need, for example, can I create a list of queries and analyzes (some even complex, for which we will write python script) save them in some way and allow the user to reuse them? 
P.s. I don't know if I'm writing in the right place, let me know if I must write these things in a new question.